# Python Django encode french accented character when saving but Django admin works

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I'm working with french content.
I have integrated the Django Admin into my project. 
MySQL is my database...
When i add a new Product (Model) from the Admin board the special characters a saved into the database correctly.

**But when i call the method *save()* on the model myself the characters are somehow encoded in something like this \xe90**

I'm using Beautifulsoup to crawl contents on the web....

Answer (score 0):

Your data is coming in encoded. You need to decode it as `latin-1`. See this example:

```
In [24]: b'\xe9'.decode('latin-1')
Out[24]: 'é'
```

See this page for more information on handling it in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/unicode/

Comment: Where am i suppose to decode it ? where in my serializer ?